# firebase how to deploy only specific function of express() app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I use an Express app on cloud functions deployed with the Firebase CLI. What is the way to deploy only one specific function?

```
const app = express();

app.post('/sample-1', (req, res) => {
  //
});

app.post('/sample-2', (req, res) => {
  //
});
```

when I try:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:app
```

it deploys all app functions (`sample-1`, `sample-2` ... )

Is there a way to deploy only a specific Eexpress app function like `sample-1` ?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.  The entire express app will be updated every time.  In the end, it is really just one function that has internal routing for each path.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy only ***sample-1*** or ***sample-2*** because both are in ***app***, although you make make another instance of express() -> ***const appv2 = express();*** or something like that to export it in the end but you have to measure you benefit of all that.

```
const app = express();
const appV2 = express();

app.post('/sample-1', (req, res) => {
  //
});

appV2.post('/sample-2', (req, res) => {
  //
});
```